# Start chapter numbering not from 1?

Tags: numbering, lyx

Can I set chapter numbering in book document class not start from 1? I want the chapter to start from 9. Can I do this to another environment like section or equation? I'm using LyX.

Comment: did you tried  `\setcounter{chapter}{8}`? works for section and equation, too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`\setcounter{chapter}{8}` or `\addtocounter{chapter}{8}` should do the trick.

Add one of these in an ERT (inserted with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>, or Insert --> TeX Code) just before the chapter heading.

Comment: To clarify, you can do this with any counter (section, equation, footnote). See [the wikibook on counters](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Counters) for a full list.